# what does "event =&gt" does in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I came across this code below but I don't understand why we are doing event is equal and greater than and then console.log 
 I would really appreciate if someone explains it

```
const node = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');

const input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(node, 'input');

input$.subscribe({
  next: event =&gt; console.log(`You just typed ${event.target.value}!`),
  error: err =&gt; console.log(`Oops... ${err}`),
  complete: () =&gt; console.log(`Complete!`),
});

const input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(node, 'input')
  .map(event =&gt; event.target.value)
  .filter(value =&gt; value.length &gt;= 2)
  .subscribe(value =&gt; {
    // use the `value`
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Javascript code that's been passed through an [HTML sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization).

The original code using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) should be as follows:

```js
const node = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');

const input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(node, 'input');

input$.subscribe({
  next: event => console.log(`You just typed ${event.target.value}!`),
  error: err => console.log(`Oops... ${err}`),
  complete: () => console.log(`Complete!`),
});

const input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(node, 'input')
  .map(event => event.target.value)
  .filter(value => value.length >= 2)
  .subscribe(value => {
    // use the `value`
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid JavaScript. `=&gt` should be `=>` and what you're seeing is simply ES6's [arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/).

This is a display bug in the page you're seeing. It probably stems from the fact that `<` and `>` in HTML text should be transformed into `&lt;` and `&gt;` so as not to cause parse errors with the same characters when they serve as tag opening and closing (as in `<div>`).